# What photoshop filter is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

I applied a simple photoshop filter to a drawing I made a while ago. Now I need to apply the same filter to a different drawing, but I can't remember which filter it was. I've tried every filter, and neither comes even close to what I did.

If you know which filter is this, please let me know.

[image: unkown filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the "Rough Pastels" filter in Photoshop.

You can find it in Filter > Artistic > "Rough Pastels..."

Comment: Yep, that was it. The default settings didn't seem like that was the filter at first sight, but with maximum stroke length, detail and scaling, I got the desired effect.